# Complicated IF statement returning false

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am using this long `IF` statement to calculate the commission rate for sales people. The value if true portion works but the value if false returns `FALSE` in the cell instead of executing the false instruction which in this case is `(IF(R11<1,(H11*($C$7/10000)),H11*R11)`. Maybe I cannot have another `IF` in the False section of the formula?

If the main `IF` statement is `FALSE` (meaning Q11 is blank) I want the false portion of the formula to then
test if R11 is blank and if it is blank then `(H11*($C$7/10000))`
if R11 is not blank then `H11*R11`

Can someone help me get this right?

```
=IF(Q11>1,(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)),(H11*1%),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)),(H11*0.5%),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)),(H11*0.3%),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11)),(H11*0.5%),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11)),(H11*1%),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)),(H11*0%),(IF(R11<1,(H11*($C$7/10000)),H11*R11))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For any other people who visit this page as well. Here is an unwrapped version of the authors if statement.

```
=IF(
    Q11>1,
    (IF(
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)),
        (H11*1%),
        IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)),
            (H11*0.5%),
            IF(
                ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)),
                (H11*0.3%),
                IF(
                    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11)),
                    (H11*0.5%),
                    IF(
                        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11)),
                        (H11*1%),
                        IF(
                            ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)),
                            (H11*0%),
                            (IF(
                                R11<1,
                                (H11*($C$7/10000)),
                                H11*R11
                            ))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ))
)
```

Sorry I know you never asked to recreate it, but it was really hard to read, maintain and change. What about this?

```
=IFS(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11))), (H11*1%), OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11))), (H11*0.5%), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)), (H11*0.3%), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)), (H11*0%)), R11<1,(H11*($C$7/10000)), H11*R11, TRUE, $C$1)
```

Easier to read:

```
=IFS(
    OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11))),
    (H11*1%),
    OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11))),
    (H11*0.5%),
    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)),
    (H11*0.3%),
    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)),
    (H11*0%)),
    R11<1,
    (H11*($C$7/10000)),
    H11*R11,
    TRUE,
    $C$1)
```

The TRUE is just my way of forcing a else statement on IFS, $C$1 will by the else statement. Or you could just have two ifs statements embedded in a single if statement

```
=IF(
    Q11 > 1,
    (IFS(
        OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11))),
        (H11*1%),
        OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11))),
        (H11*0.5%),
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)),
        (H11*0.3%),
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)),
        (H11*0%)),
        R11<1,
        (H11*($C$7/10000)),
        H11*R11)),
    (IFS(
        OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("COOP",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UNITED",Q11))),
        (H11*1%),
        OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CERBASI",Q11)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Specialist",Q11))),
        (H11*0.5%),
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Direct",Q11)),
        (H11*0.3%),
        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Subordinate",F11)),
        (H11*0%),
        R11<1,
        (H11*($C$7/10000)),
        H11*R11)))
```

Comment: Thanks Monofuse but the formula has a syntax error in it that I can't detect so excel is not accepting, can you repost it copied directly from your excel?